# How to Drag and Drop to save a link in chrome?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

When dragging a link (such as a link to a pdf) from chrome to a folder, I'd like it to save the pdf, not an internet shortcut. Is there an extension already made for this?

Comment: Why not right-click on the link and use `Save Link As...`?

Comment: That's what I currently do, but it has the problem that it opens up its own file save dialog, and I have to re-navigate to the folder.

Comment: @Dennis done (Windows 8).

Comment: It seems that you got solution, you can share it here - it might be helpful to others.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get a solution. I was just trying to tell Kruug that I added the operating system tag.